# how to control video in php

Tags: php, video

I have a video.

I create the file PHP to view video (view.php)

In this file, I create token save two times on database

I use embed to get the data of the file in the file get.php

example:

```
<embed src="get.php?v=filename&t=token"></embed>
```

In get.php file, I use file_get_content() function to get data video file and echo it, have use header ("content-type: video/mp4")

In view.php file, videos play successfully, but I can not control it

how to I can solve this problem?

Code view.php

```
    <?php
        if (count($_GET) == 1 && count($_POST == 0) && isset($_GET['v'])){
            $token = substr(md5($_GET['v']), 0, 20);
            $time = time();
            $token = $time . $token;
            require_once ('./global.php');
            require_once ('./include/database.php');
            $db = new Database();
            if ($db->insert( 'token', array( 'tokencode' => $token ) )){
                if ($db->insert( 'token', array( 'tokencode' => $token ) )){
        ?>
        <embed src="./get.php?v=<?php echo $_GET['v'] ?>&t=<?php echo $token; ?>" width="900" height="550" type="video/mp4"></embed>
        <?php
            } }

}
```

code get.php

```
<?php

if (count($_GET) == 2 && count($_POST) == 0 && isset($_GET['v']) && isset($_GET['t'])){
    require_once ('./global.php');
    require_once ('./include/database.php');
    $db = new Database();

    $numT = $db->count('token', 'tokenid', array(array( 'tokencode', $_GET['t'] )));
    if ($numT > 0){
        $listT = $db->selectMultiple('token', array(array( 'tokencode', $_GET['t'] )));
        if (count($listT) > 1){
            $where = array(array( 'tokencode', $_GET['t'], '&&' ), array( 'tokenid', $listT[0]['tokenid'] ));
        }else{
            $where = array(array( 'tokencode', $_GET['t'] ));
        }
        if ($db->delete('token', $where)){
            $f = file_get_contents('ch01-01.mp4');
            unset($db);
            header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
            echo $f;
        }
    }
}
```

demo : http://newbieitvn.tk/view.php?v=ch01-01